# Pivot Table: Hide rows where two columns are not null

Tags: oracle11g, analytics, pivot-table, obiee

I have a column called Test Name. Within this column, I have several attributes, of which I am only looking at two (we will call the attributes Red and Blue). This is how the basic table looks:

[image: Basic Table]

Now I converted this table into a pivot table. Note that Test Result is not a measure, so I applied a random aggregation rule (in this case Max) to force OBIEE to show data in the measures field. This is how the pivot table looks:

[image: Pivot Table]

What I want to do is only keep rows in the pivot table where both Blue and Red have some sort of value in it. In this example I would only keep Sample Number 3304 and 3305.

Remember that Blue and Red are only attributes of the Test Name column, so I can't simply use a filter saying where Test Name or Test Result is not null. Also, these are not metrics, so building custom formulas is quite tricky.

Comment: Have you tried using Selection Steps? Without the dataset/RPD to hack about with, I can't say for sure it would work, but it would be my first plan of attack from what you describe.

Comment: Yep. They alter the column those attributes are derived from, but not the attributes themselves. I am limited on what I can do within the RPD as this is a production environment and change is not something that comes quickly. I solved my question here with what I think is a  workaround, and I will post that as the answer later if nothing else comes up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I knew my natural key (in this case sample number and org number together), I created a subreport that returned sample numbers and org numbers concatenated together (so they were 100% unique) that had a value for the RED attribute (since the BLUE attribute always had a value, and always will).

In the main report, I simply filtered my sample number org number combination by the sub report, then hid that column and only showed sample number. This seems to work well.